# How to export foreground collection objects without changing it's light setup?

Tags: lighting, layers

[My scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lViuH.jpg)

[image: Foreground object isolated]

If anybody can provide send a link to a tutorial how to export separatly my objects, when i isolate my foreground the hdri makes everything bright.

Comment: EDIT: Trying hold out in the layers panel does not work,
I've put everything except the foreground objects in a collection.